# Move/combine state between Terraform modules?

Tags: terraform

I have a bunch of modules set up like this:

```
module "by01" {
  source          = "./modules/app_db"
  droplet_name    = "by01"
  droplet_slug    = "s-2vcpu-2gb"
  droplet_image   = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
  droplet_region  = "ams3"
  droplet_tags    = ["U1804", "TAG_HERE"]
  ssh_fingerprint = var.ssh_fingerprint
  user_password   = var.user_password
  pvt_key         = var.pvt_key
  pub_key         = var.pub_key
}
```

The module creates a digitalocean droplet, as well as setting up some basic DNS and a floating IP. The thought was that I then could switch out servers when upgrading OS etc.

What I DIDN'T think about is that when I set up a new server, I'd want to destroy the old server. I then lose the floating IP and DNS setup.

Is there a way around this, or what would be a recommended way of setting this up?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Without seeing how your module works or how you intend to swap out servers it's hard to tell what to do better here. If you are creating another module alongside and then need to use the floating IP and DNS from another module then you are going to have problems and it feels like you're working at the wrong abstraction there. Either you need to split out the shared stuff or you need to have the module handle replacing the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to remove the resources I did not want to destroy from state:

```
    $ terraform state rm module.by_old.digitalocean_domain.a_record
    $ terraform state rm module.by_old.digitalocean_domain.a_wildcard
    $ terraform state rm module.by_old.digitalocean_floating_ip.floating_ip
```